# Android Sqlite doesn't update

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to update one or more rows at the table in Android, and all it's correct, and the *documentId* exist, but doesn't update nothing, but if I try to update without conditional all is updated

this is the code

```
 public void updatePendingDocs(int documentId) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DOCS_Done, 1);

    String[] args = new String[]{(documentId+"")};
    try {
        db.update(Table_Name_Doc, cv, DOCS_ID + " =? ", args);
            Log.i("DBHelper", "good");
    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex){
        Log.e("DBHelper", "Error "+ ex);
    }
        db.close();
}
```

In the console the message is good, but when I check the table, the value wasn't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If `DOCS_ID` data type is `TEXT`, then try this way

```
 public void updatePendingDocs(int documentId) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DOCS_Done, 1);

    String[] args = new String[]{("'"+documentId+"'")};
    try {
        db.update(Table_Name_Doc, cv, DOCS_ID + " =? ", args);
            Log.i("DBHelper", "good");
    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex){
        Log.e("DBHelper", "Error "+ ex);
    }
        db.close();
}
```